# Observable forkJoin not firing

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm trying to use `forkJoin` on two Observables. One of them starts as a stream... If I subscribe to them directly I get a response, `forkJoin` isn't firing though. Any ideas?

```
private data$: Observable<any[]>;
private statuses$: Observable<any[]>;
private queryStream = new Subject<string>();    

....

this.data$ = this.queryStream
    .startWith('')
     .flatMap(queryInput => {
            this.query = queryInput
            return this._companyService.getCompanies(this.queryRequired + ' ' + this.query, this.page, this.sort);
                })
            .share();
    
...

Observable.forkJoin(this.statuses$, this.companies$)
            .subscribe(res => {
                console.log('forkjoin');
                this._countStatus(res[0], res[1]);
            });


// This shows arrays in the console...

this.statuses$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
this.companies$.subscribe(res => console.log(res));

// In the console
Array[9]
Array[6]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A very common problem with `forkJoin` is that it requires all source Observables to emit at least one item and all of them have to complete.

In other words if `this.statuses$` or `this.companies$` doesn't emit any item and until they both complete the `forkJoin` won't emit anything.

```
this.statuses$.subscribe(
    res => console.log(res),
    undefined,
    () => console.log('completed'),
);
```

Comment: They both emit items, if I subscribe and console log I can see the arrays they emit. I've updated the question to reflect this. Thanks

Comment: @nick And do both of them complete?

Comment: I'm not sure, what's the best way to tell? And if not, how do I make them complete? The issue seems to be with the `queryStream: Subject`, I just create a straight `Observable` it works...

Comment: `Subject` doesn't complete until you tell it to do so. So you need to call `queryStream.complete()` manually. But this depends on your application logic, maybe you could use just `take(1)` without completing the `Subject`. See the update how to check the Observable completes

Answer (score 56):

`forkJoin` emits only when all inner observables have completed. 
If you need an equivalent of `forkJoin` that just listens to a single emission from each source, use `combineLatest` + `take(1)`

```
combineLatest(
  this.statuses$,
  this.companies$,
)
.pipe(
  take(1),
)
.subscribe(([statuses, companies]) => {
  console.log('forkjoin');
  this._countStatus(statuses, companies);
});
```

As soon as both sources emit, `combineLatest` will emit and `take(1)` will unsubscribe immediately after that.

Comment: The problem with combineLatest is the fact that it returns data for the observable that fired first. I had to change to forkjoin because I need to wait for both observables to wait on one another.

Comment: For anyone looking for a solution that only emits when all observables inside `combineLatest` have emitted at least once, use `skipWhile` or `filter` to prevent `combineLatest` from emitting until they all pass the provided predicate function.

Comment: I tried to set of() in forkJoin's parameter but it still did not emit the subscribe()

Answer (score 6):

The `forkJoin` didn't work so I used the below code to solve my problem. With `mergeMap` you can map the result of the outer subscription to the inner subscription and subscribe to it as you wish

```
this.statuses$.pipe(
    mergeMap(source => this.companies$.pipe(
        map(inner => [source , inner])
        )
    )
).subscribe(([e , r]) => {
    console.log(e , r);
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Appending `.pipe(take(1))` as a pipe for `asObservable()`-like observables will do the job.

```
forkJoin({
    l0: this._svc.data$.pipe(take(1)),
    l1: this._api.getLogman1(),
    l2: this._api.getLogman2(),
    l3: this._api.getLogman3(),
})
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll),
    )
    .subscribe(x => {
        console.log(x);
    });
```

Comment: Wow, this fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned on other responses forkJoin seems to not work because it does not have the same function as subscribe.

Subscribe will be triggered when it receives a **next or completed** event but forkJoin will only fire when all the observable are **completed**.

The difference with combineLatest is that it will be triggered if your observable send all a **next or completed** event and forkJoin will only trigger if your Observable send all a **completed** event.

Therefore your code will not work if your event send **next** event but this code should work :

```
combineLatest([this.statuses$, this.companies$])
        .subscribe(res => {
            console.log('combineLatest');
            this._countStatus(res[0], res[1]);
        });
```

You can see in the documentation of rxjs that in your case combineLastest is the best answer : https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin

Doc to combineLatest https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Doc to Observable and the different event that you could trigger : https://rxjs.dev/guide/observable

Answer (score 2):

For me the `combineLatest` operator was the solution!

Comment: same here... I have no idea why forkJoin was not working... but combineLatest did

Answer (score 1):

```
Observable.forkJoin([
      _someService.getUsers(),
      _someService.getCustomers(),
    ])
      .subscribe((data: [Array<User>, Array<Customer>]) => {
        let users: Array<User> = data[0];
        let customer: Array<Customer> = data[1];
      }, err => {
      });





      //someService
        getUsers():Observable<User> {
          let url = '/users';
          return this._http.get(url, headers)
            .map(res => res.json());
        }

        getCustomers():Observable<Customer> {
          let url = '/customers';
          return this._http.get(url, headers)
            .map(res => res.json());
        }
```